# asp.net send duplicate email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

every time i clicked the button then i will received the duplicate emails.What wrong with my coding? Below is my asp.net code behind(VB.net) code. Please help, thank you

```
    Using sw As New StringWriter()
        Using hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            GridView2.RenderControl(hw)
            Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
            Dim mm As New MailMessage("gmail", "gmail")
            mm.Subject = "Testing email"
            mm.Body = "Testing email <br/> <hr />" + sw.ToString() & "<br/ <br/>"
            mm.IsBodyHtml = True
            Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            smtp.EnableSsl = True
            Dim NetworkCred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential()
            NetworkCred.UserName = "my gmail address"
            NetworkCred.Password = "my password"
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred
            smtp.Port = 587
            smtp.Send(mm)
            End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: It is likely that the duplication is coming from somewhere else.  Is there any more of you code that shows you how this code is called?

Comment: Hi bro, this is the only code i using...

Comment: Add some code to log when this is called and see if it is called twice by checking that log.  I suspect that the method is called twice and the code shown here is perfectly fine.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your advice bro....